# Openpyxl - How to read int value from cells in excel file

Tags: openpyxl

I have the following sample code;

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

print "Going to execute the script"

workbook = load_workbook("SampleExcel.xlsx", use_iterators = True)

for worksheet in workbook:
    for row in worksheet.iter_rows():
        for cell in row:
            if(cell.internal_value != None):
                print cell.internal_value           

print "End of script execution"
```

Some cells in my excel files have non-decimal values like 1, 22, 732 etc. But cell.internal_value is giving me these values as 1.0, 22.0, 732.0 etc. How can I get the number values as it is seen in excel file?

Ps: I am using openpyxl version 1.8.5. But I have tried the latest version of openpyxl 2.1.0 by changing `cell.internal_value` to `cell.value` and the same problems exists there as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with openpyxl package which has been resolved. Now `cell.value` gives correct value as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `cell.internal_value`? In general, `cell.value` will give you what you want. If openpyxl is returning floats, then this is because the numbers are stored like this in your file.

Comment: In openpyxl 1.8.5 we have to use cell.internal_value because RawCell doesn't have 'name' property. This was changed in a later version of openpyxl and with the latest versions we have to use cell.value. I mentioned about this at the end of my question.

Comment: Number are entered as integer values in the cells of excel file. But I am getting it as float values with single decimal place.

Comment: Just looking at the code and it looks like we always cast numbers to floats (they are strings in the source file). This could be changed to try ints first. Please submit a bug with a sample file.

Comment: Issue raised with sample file. Please see https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issue/364/openpyxl-how-to-read-int-value-from-cells